# Can't sign up for meta.apple.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, user-accounts, sign-up

I'm having difficulty signing up for meta.apple.stackexchange.com. When I click "signup" and choose my Google account, I'm taken back to the question *without* the typical flow of allowing access to Gmail info.

When I click on "comment", I'm asked to sign in with Google, but I'm immediately blocked for suspicious activity:

[image]

I don't think I've ever been blocked on the SE sites, and I know I have not offended anyone on Apple SE (yet?).

Should I be using Safari instead of Firefox? Or should I be using a different finger to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>?

Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Thanks @3ventic. There's no answer, and I'm not even sure if its the same issue. For example, I checked my IP, and its the same IP that I was using yesterday.